# selenium not findning a xpath when i dont want to find it

Tags: python, selenium

I am writing a little script checking if a specific title is on my local library. the program I tried to write is a simple if-then program.

```
ferdig_liste=[]



for line in listed:

driver= webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
url="https://libbyapp.com/search/deichman/search/query-"+line+"/page-1"
driver.get(url)
verdi=driver.find_element(by="xpath", value="/html/body/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/section[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/span")
if verdi== None:
  ferdig_liste.append(line)
```

what I am trying to do is every time that specific Xpath is not on the page they have that book, but every time it runes it starts to crack seeing as the XPath is not on this page? any idea on how to work around it?

Comment: `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/section[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/span")` use this instead of `driver.find_element(by="xpath", value="/html/body/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/section[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/span")`

Comment: XPath is brittle in nature since it is an absolute xapth. Please use relative xapth for UI automation, we can guide you on that, but for that you will have to share the exact page URL or relevant HML in text format here.